# Grouping and counting data by months in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, grouping

As I exemplify in the image below, I have a table named `fruits`. This table shows the number of fruits according to the given days.

[image]

I can also formulate it as Json like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2023-01-17",
    "apple": 14,
    "pear": 2,
    "orange": 2,
    "banana": 1,
    "cherry": 5,
    "avacado": 3,
    "kiwi": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2023-01-18",
    "apple": 9,
    "pear": 1,
    "orange": 6,
    "banana": 5,
    "cherry": 4,
    "avacado": 0,
    "kiwi": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2023-01-19",
    "apple": 8,
    "pear": 0,
    "orange": 2,
    "banana": 5,
    "cherry": 0,
    "avacado": 3,
    "kiwi": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2023-01-20",
    "apple": 12,
    "pear": 3,
    "orange": 3,
    "banana": 2,
    "cherry": 4,
    "avacado": 0,
    "kiwi": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2023-01-22",
    "apple": 1,
    "pear": 0,
    "orange": 7,
    "banana": 0,
    "cherry": 8,
    "avacado": 9,
    "kiwi": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "date": "2023-01-30",
    "apple": 11,
    "pear": 3,
    "orange": 0,
    "banana": 1,
    "cherry": 0,
    "avacado": 0,
    "kiwi": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "date": "2023-02-01",
    "apple": 7,
    "pear": 0,
    "orange": 7,
    "banana": 2,
    "cherry": 6,
    "avacado": 4,
    "kiwi": 8
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "date": "2023-02-03",
    "apple": 3,
    "pear": 8,
    "orange": 1,
    "banana": 7,
    "cherry": 5,
    "avacado": 0,
    "kiwi": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "date": "2023-02-06",
    "apple": 12,
    "pear": 0,
    "orange": 1,
    "banana": 4,
    "cherry": 0,
    "avacado": 1,
    "kiwi": 5
  }
]
```

And the object structure is like this:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Apple { get; set; }
    public int Pear { get; set; }
    public int Orange { get; set; }
    public int Banana { get; set; }
    public int Cherry { get; set; }
    public int Avacado { get; set; }
    public int Kiwi { get; set; }
}
```

I got the data in the Json file using Json.Net as follows:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Fruit>>(File.ReadAllText("fruits.json"));
```

I want to process this data by month like below with using Linq Lambda, but I have no idea how to do it.

[image]

Comment: You could `GroupBy` month/year and then select the count of each type from each group into a new `Fruit` object

Comment: What have you tried so far? Search engines will return a lot of good tutorials when searching for linq and group by ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `GroupBy` the month/year and then select the sum of each type of fruit from each group into a new Fruit object, so you have a list of fruits that each represent the sum for that month/year:

```
List<Fruit> combined = json
    .GroupBy(fruit => new DateTime(fruit.Date.Year, fruit.Date.Month, 1))
    .Select(group => new Fruit
    {
        Date = group.Key,
        Apple = group.Sum(fruit => fruit.Apple),
        Pear = group.Sum(fruit => fruit.Pear),
        Orange = group.Sum(fruit => fruit.Orange),
        Banana = group.Sum(fruit => fruit.Banana),
        Cherry = group.Sum(fruit => fruit.Cherry),
        Avacado = group.Sum(fruit => fruit.Avacado),
        Kiwi = group.Sum(fruit => fruit.Kiwi)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Then this list could be output into a table. Here's a rough way to do it in a console window:

```
Console.WriteLine("Date\t\tApple\tPear\tOrange\tBanana\tCherry\tAvocado\tKiwi");

foreach(var fruit in combined)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{fruit.Date.ToString("MMMM yyyy")}\t{fruit.Apple}\t{fruit.Pear}\t{fruit.Orange}\t{fruit.Banana}\t{fruit.Cherry}\t{fruit.Avacado}\t{fruit.Kiwi}");
}

Console.Write("\n\nDone. Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
Date            Apple   Pear    Orange  Banana  Cherry  Avocado Kiwi
January 2023    55      9       20      14      21      15      7
February 2023   22      8       9       13      11      5       14


Done. Press any key to exit...
```

Comment: Can I use `group.Key` by 2 times? What if I create an element called `public string DateString { get; set; }` inside the `Fruit` object and use it as `group.Key.ToString("yyyy-MMMM")`? This usage gives me an error like this: `SQLiteException: SQLite error no such column: C8`. I don't understand. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: The group `Key` is simply the property of the object that was used to do the grouping, so if you had a string property and wanted to group by that, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq to group the data using the `GroupBy` method. You'll want to group by year and month:

```
List<Fruit> fruit = ... // read in the data here
var groupedFruit = fruit.GroupBy(fruit => (Year: fruit.Date.Year, Month: fruit.Date.Month))
```

You'll then want to be able to extract the data for each grouping, how you do this is up to you (most likely you'll loop through it and pull out the information you need). A contrived example for a specific year and month is given below:

```
var january2023 = groupedFruit.Where(group => group.Key.Year == 2023 && group.Key.Month == 1);
var january2023Apples = january2023.Select(group => group.Sum(f => f.Apple));
```